# Обновить значения элемента массива

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Столкнулся с ошибкой при обновлении значения. Передаю значения, но стейт не обновляется. Ищу по переданному id. В итоге массив NewArr получает неверные данные

```
state = {
mobile : [
  {"id": 0, "name": "Dima", "phone": 12345},
  {"id": 1, "name": "Ira", "phone": 67890},
]

 saveItem = (name,phone,id) => {
let NewArr = this.state.mobile;
NewArr = NewArr.map(el => {
  if (el.id === id) {
    el.name = name;
    el.phone = phone
  }
  return NewArr;
})
this.setState({
  mobile: NewArr,
  read:false
})
```

Пытаюсь обновить так, но  не знаю как найти индекс NewMobile[index]. Скорее всего в filter, по как передать наружу не получается

```
    const newItem = {
  id: id,
  name: text,
  phone: phone
}
let NewArray = this.state.mobile.filter(el => el.id === id);
const a = this.state.mobile.indexOf(NewArray);
NewArray = newItem;
const NewMobile = this.state.mobile;
NewMobile[a] = NewArray;
this.setState({
  mobile: NewMobile

})
```

Comment: нужно сохранить новый элемент в массив, в случае если у них разные id?

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn Tereshyn  нет, если id исправленного = id в массиве, требуется обновить новыми входными данными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Никогда не мутируйте состояние, нужно сделать копию массива, в идеале deep copy.
2. Используйте деструктуризацию.
3. Filter, map и т д создают новый массив на основании условий.. вам нужно записать новый элемент. То есть добавьте в мою реализацию просто условие, в котором проверяйте, есть ли в старом массиве `id`, если есть, то не добавляйте новый элемент, если нет, то добавляйте
4. Название mobile не сильно хорошо отображает то, что оно хранит
5. Лучше входным параметром в функцию `saveMobile` использовать объект, а не каждый параметр по отдельности. При использовании каждого параметра по отдельности велика вероятность перепутать порядок и вообще ошибиться

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Some />
    </div>
  );
}

class Some extends React.Component {
  state = {
    phoneNumbers: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Dima",
        phone: 12345
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Ira",
        phone: 67890
      }
    ]
  };

  saveMobile = obj => {
    const { phoneNumbers } = this.state;
    const clonePhoneNumbers = [...phoneNumbers];
    const contact = clonePhoneNumbers.find(mobile => mobile.id === obj.id);
    if (contact) {
      contact.name = obj.name;
      contact.phone = obj.phone;
    } else {
      clonePhoneNumbers.push({
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.name,
        phone: obj.phone
      });
    }
    this.setState(() => ({
      phoneNumbers: clonePhoneNumbers
    }));
  };

  renderMobileNumbers = mobiles =>
    mobiles.map(({ id, name, phone }) => (
      <div key={id}>
        <p> id: {id} </p>
        <p> name: {name} </p>
        <p> phone: {phone} </p>
      </div>
    ));

  render() {
    const { phoneNumbers } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderMobileNumbers(phoneNumbers)}
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            this.saveMobile({ id: 92, name: "vlad", phone: 2121321 })
          }
        >
          save
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            this.saveMobile({ id: 92, name: "eeee", phone: 2121321 })
          }
        >
          save
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: если я понимаю, вы пушите новый эл в массив, а мне требуется если id совпадают,  обновить новыми значениями

Comment: @ДмитрийСухоцкий обновил

Comment: не могу понять где вы обновляете текущее значение? в contact это елемент, вы в неге пишите значения и дальше нигде ничему его не присваиваете.

Comment: @ДмитрийСухоцкий вы запускали пример??

Comment: @ДмитрийСухоцкий я беру `contact` из массива, который клонировал, меняю у него поля объекта, потом присваиваю массиву `phoneNumbers` массив `clonePhoneNumbers`...

Comment: спасибо я тебя понял. Подскажи, добавляю в данное приложение router. на / - отображается таблица, на /read будет добавление или редактирование. Как передавать пропсы ? redux не предлагать, какие есть варианты

Comment: в роутере тебе нужно рендерить скрины, а на скринах компоненты, в которые ты будешь передавать пропсы.

Comment: если тебе кажется, что у тебя не получается шарить пропсы между компонентами без редакса, то скорее всего, ты что-то неправильно делаешь. я подчеркну - СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО, а не сто процентов